# Chemfig illustration in a tabular environment appears out of the box

Tags: tables, chemfig, chemistry

I need to prepare a sum-up for my student. But when I mix `chemfig` with tabular environment, the Lewis structures are out of the box.
How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}  % Type d'écrit
\usepackage{geometry}          % Début package
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros,chemformula}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{modiagram}
\usepackage{epic,carom}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\setatomsep{2.5em}
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm} % Marges
\title{Les principales produits en chimie \heart} % Titre du document
\author{} % Auteur
\date{} % Date
\begin{document}
\maketitle{}

\section{Acides et Bases importantes}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
    \toprule
    Formules & Représentation\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(l){3-3}
        Acide Chlorhydrique (dans l'eau) & $(H^+_{aq} + Cl^-_{aq})$\\ 
        \midrule
        Chlorure d'Hydrogène (gaz) & \chemfig{H-Cl}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Bromhydrique & \chemfig{H-Br}\\ 
        \midrule
        Acide Iodhydrique & \chemfig{H-I}\\ 
        \midrule
        Acide Fluorhydrique & \chemfig{H-F}\\ 
        \midrule
        Acide Cyanhydrique & \chemfig{H-C~N}\\ 
        \midrule
        Acide Sulfhydrique & \chemfig{H_2-S}\\ 
        \midrule
    Acide Nitrique & \chemfig{N(-[5]\lewis{357,O}^{-})(=[2]\lewis{13,O})(-[7]\lewis{57,O}-[1]H)}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}   
\end{center}
```

Here the result:
[image]

Comment: Try `\Lewis` (with capital L)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ypu can use `cellspace`, which defines minimal vertical padding at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`(or `C` if you load `siunitx`).

*Unrelated*: the babel option `francais` is now  called `french` and should preferably be loaded with the document class, so that all language dependent packages be informed. Also, you should use the `utf8` input encoding nowadays.

```
\documentclass[12pt, french]{article} % Type d'écrit
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{geometry} % Début package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{6pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{6pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{chemist}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemmacros, chemformula}
%\usepackage{modiagram}
%\usepackage{epic,carom}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\setchemfig{atom sep=2.5em}
\geometry{top=1.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, hmargin=2cm} % Marges
\title{Les principaux produits en chimie \faHeart} % Titre du document
\author{} % Auteur
\date{} % Date
\begin{document}

\maketitle{}

\section{Acides et Bases importants}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cSc}
    \toprule
    Formules & Représentation\\
    \cmidrule(r){1-1} \cmidrule(lr){2-2}
        Acide Chlorhydrique (dans l'eau) &  (\ce{H^+_{aq} + Cl^-_{aq}})\\
        \midrule
        Chlorure d'Hydrogène (gaz) & \chemfig{H-Cl}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Bromhydrique & \chemfig{H-Br}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Iodhydrique & \chemfig{H-I}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Fluorhydrique & \chemfig{H-F}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Cyanhydrique & \chemfig{H-C~N}\\
        \midrule
        Acide Sulfhydrique & \chemfig{H_2-S}\\
        \midrule
    Acide Nitrique & \chemfig{N(-[5]\lewis{357,O}^{-})(=[2]\lewis{13,O})(-[7]\lewis{57,O}-[1]H)}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer :D
It works, but hy do you use the \ce{H+}_\text{aq} ?

Comment: `\ce` because  symbols of chemical elements are  upright, not italic as in maths formulæ, and `chemformula` cares for that (as well as the `+` in exponent) . `\text{aq}` is similarly  to have `aq`  upright, not as the product of two (italic) variables.

Comment: Ok perfect,
Thanks for your answer ! :)

Comment: @Bernard f´the funny thing is: `\ce` is a `mhchem` command ;) (the one from `chemformula` is called `\ch`)

Comment: @clemens: Yes, I know (albeit a non-chemist…). I used this one, because I had problems with the chemical equation in the second row (probably due to my limited knowledge of `chemformula` ) – I don't remember which, maybe obtaining upright indices.

Comment: Both `\ce{H^+_{aq} + Cl^-_{aq}}` with version 4 of `mhchem` and `\ch{H^+_{aq} + Cl^-_{aq}}` with `chemformula` should work :)

Comment: I've checked: it indeed works with `mhchem`, so I replaced this part of the code (thanks!), but with `\ch`  I have two problems: the index and the exponent are right-aligned, and `+` is replaced with the congruence sign (`≡`)  for  a reason I don't understand.

Comment: The replacement happens when you don't leave spaces around the `+`. It then represents a triple bond. The superscript is shifted to the right when there also is a subscript because IUPAC recommends a staggered alignment of sub- and superscripts. I agree that in this case it doesn't look good but there is an option to turn the shift off. (IUPAC also recommends to _not_ subscript the phase identifier but that's another story)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the information!